# public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im develope the  MVC user Profile Image Uplaoder,i cant update database display the following error,please give me a solution? what are the missing ?

```
 Error  2   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'eData.DataClases.Masters.HttpPostedFileBase' is less accessible than property 'Data.KdbContext.ProfileImage' C:\Users\Mad\Videos\Projects2015\eData\DataClases\Masters\MasterContext.cs  117 32  eData
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using eData.DataClases.Masters;

namespace eData
{
   public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not posted the relevant code!

Comment: public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }

Comment: That has got nothing to do with it! See Davids answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you have a custom `HttpPostedFileBase` class defined.  Presumably like this:

```
namespace eData.DataClases.Masters
{
    private class HttpPostedFileBase
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

(or perhaps `internal` instead of `private`)

Since your `HttpPostedFileBase` class has a more strict visibility (`private` or `internal`), you can't use it as the type for a `public` property:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }
```

This is because any consuming code which encounters that property *wouldn't be able to know the type* for that property.

Generally the fix is to either make the class' visibility match the property's, or make the property's visibility match the class'.  (Make the class `public` or make the property `private` or `internal` accordingly.)  Though, to be honest, the fact that you even have a custom implementation of `HttpPostedFileBase` is a bit strange in the first place...